# How to serialize ScyllaDB data in Rust for use with batch?

Tags: rust, traits, scylla

Is it possible to create a batch statement for dissimilar tables where values are provided in a loop in Rust? I can't just dynamically create a tuple of arbitrary size in Rust.

The second parameter to `batch` is an argument that implements `BatchValues`, which represents a list of `ValueList`. I don't know where to go from here since `ValueList` cannot be made into an object.

```
#[derive(Debug, FromRow, ValueList)]
struct Account {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, FromRow, ValueList)]
struct User {
    id: i32,
    phone_number: String,
    name: String,
}

struct DBData {
    accounts: Account,
    users: User,
}

impl BatchValues for DBData {
    type BatchValuesIter<'r> = Box<dyn ValueList>
    where
        Self: 'r;

    fn batch_values_iter(&self) -> Self::BatchValuesIter<'_> {
        return BatchValuesFromIter::new(self.accounts.into_iter().chain(self.users.into_iter()));
    }
}

async fn foo() {
    let session: Session = SessionBuilder::new().known_node(uri).build().await.unwrap();
    let mut batch = Batch::default();
    let db_data = DBData { accounts: vec![], users: vec![] };

    for account in accounts {
        batch.append_statement("INSERT INTO accounts (id, name) VALUES (?, ?);");
    }
    for user in users {
        batch.append_statement("INSERT INTO users (id, phone_number, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
    }

    session.batch(&batch, db_data).await.unwrap();
}
```

`ValueList cannot be made into an object`

I tried to serialize a structure that holds vectors of arbitrary length. The second parameter to `batch` accepts a tuple of values or a typed array. It's not possible to create a tuple dynamically without crates, and `itertools` offers tuple creation of size 15 (at most). It's also impossible to create a vector of a fixed type since some tables can be larger than others.

Therefore, I tried implementing the `BatchValues` trait which is difficult to do because `ValueList` cannot be made into an object, so I don't know how to iterate its values.